# Background sound of pick hitting string

Tags: electric-guitar, solos, picking

Whenever I try picking a string by itself (usually lower strings) it makes a background sound thats kind of like the pick rubbing against the string when I play that overshadows the actual fret sound. The sound is kind of like a thum sound

I have a feeling it’s my pick hitting the vibrating string when I play. How can I stop this?

Comment: Hi Leighton. Welcome to Music Practice & Theory SE. Your question is a bit unclear. To get the best answers, please edit it to be explicit about what you're asking.

Comment: It’s like the pick striking the strings making what I’m playing sound sloppy and unclear

Comment: The description is clear. What is the question?

Comment: I guess you're asking how to stop the noise. But it's only a guess.

Comment: Yes I wanna know if there is to stop that.

Comment: So you want to learn a better picking technique? Getting a teacher might not be a bad idea. Trying to diagnose the problems via textual messaging on this Q&A site can be difficult, but who knows, maybe it's possible. Try uploading a video on Youtube that very clearly shows what your picking hand is doing, up close and with sound. Or even an audio example, but then it'll have to be guessed what you're actually doing.

Comment: How loud is it? I realize you say it "overshadows" but just confirming. It might just be those little thumps which are similar to key clicks in other instruments

Answer (score 6):

The amount of pick sliding over the string may be the problem. Try holding the pick more gently, and changing the length it sticks out, thus not more than 3 or 4 mm showing. Also, you may be digging into the string too much.

There are times when we hold the pick differently, and attack the strings differently, for certain different sounds. You've found one.

Answer (score 0):

Dude try setting your pickups down lower in the guitar.  I think your pick is hitting the pickup.